# How to retrieve / reconstitute legible email data locally when STMP mail server copies are unavailable?

Tags: email, thunderbird, apple-mail

I have a situation where someone bulk deleted ~3000 emails from their AOL account.

We've exhausted every avenue with the mail server copies. Thankfully, it seems like a local copy of that missing data is available in OSX Mail. I made a copy of that local data from the `~/Library/Mail/` folder to another local location so it is not erased when the local copy is synced with the email server.

I can see some of the missing emails in the copied data, but they are in a git-like file structure (directories with hash names containing directories with numbers) that is not user-friendly. I have tried to import this copied local data into new osx Mail profiles and into Firebird, but neither option seems to reconstitute the data into a searchable "normal" form. Loading as .mbox doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why don't you use OSX Mail to [export](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/import-or-export-mailboxes-mlhlp1030/mac) the mails in a better format that you can import?

Comment: You may want to rewrite the subject of this post. This is about OSX mail and has nothing to do with SMTP (/STMP). A correct subject is nire likely to attract the correct people to answer this.